# show the top 3 parent (li element) but I can't figure out how to ignore the children

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show the top 3 parent (li element) but I can't figure out how to ignore the children.

For example I have the following list:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two<ul>
      <li>Two-One</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

and when I run the following code to show the first 3 elements:

```
$('#myList li:lt(3)').show();

<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two<ul>
      <li>Two-One</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

I get:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two<ul>
      <li>Two-One</li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

What I want is:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two<ul>
      <li>Two-One</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

I just want to ignore the li children elements in the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your selector to only include direct children of the parent `ul`.

```
$('#myList > li:lt(3)').show();
```

`>` is the 'child combinator' selector: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators

Answer (score 1):

You want to select the `li` elements that are only direct descendants.

```
$('#myList > li:lt(3)').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try showing all `<li>`, then specifically exclude what you don't want to show next:

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
$('li').show().css('color', 'red');
$('li + ol > li').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Don't want to show sub2.1</p>
<ol>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <ol>
    <li>sub2.1</li>
  </ol>
  <li>item3</li>
</ol>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
$('#myList > li').show().css('color','red');
$('li:nth-of-type(4)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Don't want to show Four</p>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two
    <ul>
      <li>Two-One</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```